# ¿Why this error in an ionic app which is deployed to heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, heroku, content-security-policy

I am deploying an ionic app to heroku. However, it doesn't let me to load the pages because of this error:

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOiCnqEu92Fr1Mu51QrEz0dL-vwnYh2eg.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have tried to put some code related to Content-Security-Policy. However, nothing have passed. What can I do?

Comment: "I have tried to put some code related to Content-Security-Policy. However, nothing have passed."—Please show your attempts. Otherwise we can just point you to other questions about CSP.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com;">